# AJAX Control Toolkit Autocomplete Extender not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

I can't get AJAX CT Autocomplete to work. The problem is when I start writing in textbox nothing happens. The frist problem I had experienced was when I tried to Add AutoComplete page method I got an error: "Cannot create page method "GetCompletionList"...". Then I tried creating it manually, but still nothing happens.

Here is the AdministracijaOsoba.aspx code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOsoba" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:AutoCompleteExtender
                    ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" ScriptPath="" 
                    ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" ServicePath="AdministracijaOsoba.aspx.cs" 
                    TargetControlID="txtOsoba" UseContextKey="True">
                </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Here is the AdministracijaOsoba.aspx.cs code:

```
public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
    {
        PravosudnaAkademijaEntities db = new PravosudnaAkademijaEntities();

        var osoba = from o in db.osobas
                    orderby o.osoba_prezime
                    select new { o.osoba_id, person = o.osoba_prezime + " " + o.osoba_ime };

        string[] main = new string[0];

        foreach (var o in osoba)
        {
            if (o.person.StartsWith(prefixText))
            {
                Array.Resize(ref main, main.Length + 1);
                main[main.Length - 1] = o.person.ToString();

                if (main.Length == 15)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        Array.Sort(main);
        return main;
    }
```

Take a note that I'm using LINQ to Entities. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Regards!

Comment: Just a polite code improvement suggestion...I think I'd declare a List<string>, and then myList.Add in the loop. At the end you can return myList.ToArray. This avoids the array resize hassle.

Answer (score 2):

Your code behind should read like this

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public static string[] GetCompletionList prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{....}
```

Also, there is no need of providing the servicepath attribute for your ajax extender if you are using a pagescriptmethod.

Comment: Too bad this didn't get more attention. I've been having the same problem and finally found your answer after hours of searching.

Answer (score 1):

Change your declaration to this:

```
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" 
    ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" 
    ServicePath="AdministracijaOsoba.aspx/GetCompletionList" 
    TargetControlID="txtOsoba" UseContextKey="True">
```

Add this to your AdministracijaOsoba.aspx.cs code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this wasn't helpful. My service path got underlined and still nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have in my aspx page:

```
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="tbSearchName_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" 
  DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True" ServicePath="" 
  TargetControlID="tbSearchName" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" 
  UseContextKey="True" MinimumPrefixLength="2">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

In my code behind page I have:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{
  ArrayList testList = new ArrayList();
  ...
  return (string[])testList.ToArray(typeof(string));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost right. The only problem is that the service path shouldnt end with .aspx.cs but only .aspx. If the extender is on the same page as the method then leave out servicepath

Answer (score 1):

I too have been having the same problem. I know this is a bit late, but better late than never...

Here is the setup that **finally** worked for me (with your IDs and names in place):

Code-Behind ( aspx.cs ):

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Code ( .aspx ):

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOsoba" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" 
        runat="server"
        ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
        TargetControlID="txtOsoba"  
        UseContextKey="True">
    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

As you can see, you don't need to set the ScriptPath and ServicePath properties because these properties represent...

> The path to the web service that the
>   extender will pull the word\sentence
>   completions from. If this is not
>   provided, **the service method should be
>   a page method**.

which is explained in the [AutoComplete Reference Page](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_AutoComplete_Reference.ashx). You've got your GetCompletionList() method defined in your Code-Behind, which I am currently assuming qualifies as "a page method". So, it seems you would only use the Path properties if we had the method in a different location such as a services.cs or something of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `static` keyword in your method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are missing specifying **MinimumPrefixLength** parameter of **AutoCompleteExtender**.

Answer (score 0):

Set auto-postback property of TextBox to TRUE

Answer (score -1):

Ajax autocomplete uses a service call, so you can use the below code in your aspx.cs file, Note the `System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute()` attribute, this will make the method accessible for Service call.

Alternatively you can use any [ASMX service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/863/Your-first-C-Web-Service)  or [WCF service](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahakgupta/a-simple-example-of-wcf-service/) for extensive and reliable service use.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
public static List<string> GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{
    return UserControls_phonenumbersearch.GetCompletionList(prefixText, count, contextKey);
}
```

Comment: Please try to always add a description - not just code. While this might answer the question, it will be easier to understand for the OP and anybody else reading this, when you add more details.